# jQuery to Detect Scrolling Div Position

Tags: jquery, html, css, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have a bit of problem trying to detect scrolling position on my divs. This is my code:

**index.html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="headerOne">I am a header</div>
  <div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="content">
      I am some content
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery function (not working version)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var aboveHeight = $('#headerOne').outerHeight();

$('#contentContainer').scroll(function(){
      if ($('#contentContainer').scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
      $('#headerOne').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
      } else {
      $('#headerOne').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
     }
    });
  });
```

**jQuery function (working version)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var aboveHeight = $('#headerOne').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
      $('#headerOne').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
      } else {
      $('#headerOne').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
     }
    });
  });
```

There are two different jQuery function because when I first tested I was using the **working version** and the header stays when scrolling down. But I want the header header to stay fixed user is scrolling `#contentContainer` div not the window so I change it to `$(window).` to `$('#contentContainer')` and it's not working anymore.

Can scroll feature detect div scrolling or must it be `$(window).` ?

Thank you.

Comment: you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/jsCh8/) ?

Comment: or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/jsCh8/3/) ? last one is same same as your

Comment: They both work great. Thank you.

Comment: @eicto you should have made either one of these an answer or both.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //Calculate the height of <header>
    //Use outerHeight() instead of height() if have padding
    var aboveHeight = 130;

    //when scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        //if scrolled down more than the header’s height
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){

            // if yes, add “fixed” class to the <nav>
            // add padding top to the #content 
            //(value is same as the height of the nav)
            $('nav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next()
            .css('padding-top','60px');

        } else {

            // when scroll up or less than aboveHeight,
            //remove the “fixed” class, and the padding-top
            $('nav').removeClass('fixed').next()
            .css('padding-top','0');
        }

    });
});
```